# Не доходят TCP пакеты.

Tags: сеть

Здравствуйте! Недавно закончил генератор TCP-SYN пакетов. Пакеты создаю полностью "руками"(сам ввожу адрес отправителя, получателя, размер окна и т.п.). Вроде всё работает, пакеты создаются и удаленный комп их видит... Сеть состояла из 2-х напрямую подключенных компьютеров... Проблем не было... Но вот, внезапно обнаружилось, что если посылать пакеты по сети с маршрутизаторами, мостами и с прочими штучками, то пакеты куда-то исчезают, что-то их не пропускает... Код слишком громоздок для того, чтобы его тут отображать... Что может блокировать пакеты? И почему их блокируют?

Comment: А адреса источника/получателя какие? Если из приватных, то могут и маршрутизаторы не пустить.

Comment: Адреса сетевые, есть общий для всех интернет адрес и адреса в сети... Сделал TCP клиента и сервера, но создание пакетов поручил компу - всё работает, клиент подключается и шлет данные серверу. А если пакеты "руками" делать, то что-то не доходят.

Comment: Неужели больше нет идей? Может пакет не правильно формируется и его какой-то маршрутизатор не пускает? Но может ли такой пакет выйти из сетевой карты?

Comment: может у него ttl равный единице (или нулю, это нужно уточнить) и маршрутизатор просто прибивает его, согласно правилам.

Либо пакет нарушает правила.

Comment: @Alerr, а может у Вас маршрутизаторы с NAT-ом? Он наверное (точно не знаю) по SYN пакету должен у себя таблицу переадресации строить. А их Вы наверное не делаете.

Comment: KoVadim, не, с ttl нормально, ставил 255, 65... Ничего не изменилось... Скорее пакет нарушает правила...